# Can I simplify deriving from a string type in Python?

Tags: python, types, mypy, typechecking

I derive from `str` to get strongly typed string references.  They look like below, which are redundant, and I'd like to avoid the redundancy:

```py
class VarRef(str):
    def __new__(cls, *args, **kw):
        return str.__new__(cls, *args, **kw)

class SceneRef(str):
    def __new__(cls, *args, **kw):
        return str.__new__(cls, *args, **kw)

class AmbienceRef(str):
    def __new__(cls, *args, **kw):
        return str.__new__(cls, *args, **kw)
```

This ensures, for example, that I need an explicit cast to get a `VarRef` but that otherwise it functions like a string.

I have many more and hoping there's a way to copying the same `__new__` constructor for each one.

I use these only for MyPy type checking, so at runtime it'd be fine if they were normal strings. If there is a mechanism to tag them only for type checking I'd be happy to use that approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`NewType`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#newtype) to declare a type that is functionally identical but nominal different from the base type.

```py
from typing import NewType

URL = NewType("URL", str)
fail: URL = "Hello World"  #  Incompatible types in assignment (expression has type "str", variable has type "URL")
docs: URL = URL("https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html")
```

Keep in mind that operations on the value are still defined as usual, including their types. For example, `docs + '#newtype'` will still produce a `str` instead of a `URL`.

Comment: Great, in this case I do want the operations to return normal strings.

Answer (score 1):

You, you are looking for [`typing.NewType`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.NewType), so here:

```
VarRef = typing.NewType("VarRef", str)
SceneRef = typing.NewType("SceneRef", str)
AmbienceRef = typing.NewType("AmbienceRef", str)
```

Note, at runtime, this simply returns its argument, i.e. `str`, it's only for static type checking.

Comment: Yes, at runtime I don't want a distinct type. I have other places where I do, but in those cases I'll continue to use the pattern I pasted (there are only a tiny few of those).

Comment: @edA-qamort-ora-y yeah, I was adding that for people reading this question later, just to be clear.